# How to loop test cases at certain intervals of time in selenium web-driver

Tags: java

For say i have a test case for which i have to run N times with certain intervals of times. how to do that?

code

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
public class RunMultipleTimes 
{

    @Test
    public void printNtimes()
    {
        System.out.println("This have to excecuted N time @ T intervals");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [for loop](http://beginnersbook.com/2015/03/for-loop-in-java-with-example/) to loop through your test case.

You can wait for a certain interval of time using `Thread.sleep()`. Do note, it throws an  `InterruptedException` which needs to be handled as given below:

```
public void printNtimes() throws InterruptedException
    {
        for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
        {
            //Test case steps
            Thread.sleep(T); //Here T is the interval in Milliseconds
        }
    }
```